# moq method call not being verified

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, moq

I have a test method that is failing on sso.verify notice the CheckUsername method has two await calls in a async method ? but because of that the sso verify never returns and thus is not verified. But the code is called. What would be the proper way to test this ?

```
       public void Setup()
    {
        nav = new Mock<INavService>();
        sso = new Mock<ISSOApiService>();
        _vm_Successs = new ForgotPasswordViewModel(nav.Object, sso.Object);
        sso.Setup(x => x.SendEmailCodeRequestAsync(It.IsAny<PasswordTokenRequest>())).ReturnsAsync(new StandardResponse() { ErrorCode = null }).Verifiable();
        nav.Setup(x => x.NavigateTo<ForgotPasswordEnterCodeModel, string>(It.IsAny<string>())).Verifiable(); 
    }


  [Test]
    public void CheckUserName_Success()
    {
        _vm_Successs.UserName = "Timmy";
        var response = _vm_Successs.CheckUsername();
        sso.Verify(e => e.SendEmailCodeRequest(It.IsAny<PasswordTokenRequest>()), Times.Once);
        nav.Verify(mock => mock.NavigateTo<ForgotPasswordEnterCodeModel, string>(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

This is the checkusername method

```
public async Task CheckUsername()
{
            PasswordTokenRequest r = new PasswordTokenRequest();
                await SSOAPIService.SendEmailCodeRequestAsync(r);
            await NavService.NavigateTo<ForgotPasswordEnterCodeModel, string>(UserName);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you would make the unit test itself async, and await your call to CheckUsername.  (I'm not confident enough to post as answer, but worth you trying it.)  I read this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/november/async-programming-unit-testing-asynchronous-code

Comment: so just change the test to public async Task CheckUserName_Success() ? that doesn't seem to do the trick

Comment: You're verifying `SendEmailCodeRequest` but your code actually calls `SendEmailCodeRequestAsync` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should await test method therefore you need to make your test 'async Task' type

also need to setup SendEmailCodeRequestAsync with ReturnsAsync

```
    [Test]
    public async Task ShouldDeleteAzureBlobById()
    {
        sso.Setup(x => x.SendEmailCodeRequestAsync(It.IsAny<PasswordTokenRequest>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(new StandardResponse() { ErrorCode = null })
        .Verifiable();

        _vm_Successs.UserName = "Timmy";
        var response = await _vm_Successs.CheckUsername();
        sso.Verify(e => e.SendEmailCodeRequestAsync(It.IsAny<PasswordTokenRequest>()), Times.Once);
        nav.Verify(mock => mock.NavigateTo<ForgotPasswordEnterCodeModel, string>(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
    }
```

Comment: humm I did that and no change but I would agree that should work

Comment: @MicahArmantrout try to setup SendEmailCodeRequestAsync either

Comment: I updated my question to include my setup method which includes a setup for both methods still no dice

Comment: @MicahArmantrout you need to change in setup of SendEmailCodeRequestAsync  method Returns to ReturnsAsync

Comment: Werid I don't have a method for that ..... I am using version 4.14.1

Comment: @MicahArmantrout in example you have await SSOAPIService.SendEmailCodeRequestAsync(r) is it right call to Async version?

Comment: Good call I did find that method I will get back to you on the result

Comment: Still didn't pass

Comment: @MicahArmantrout in screnshot you do verify for  SendEmailCodeRequest not for SendEmailCodeRequestAsync and it code you call "await SendEmailCodeRequestAsync "?

Comment: That was it ty for your help!